# Корректно не выполняется POST-запрос

Tags: golang

Всегда использовал Python для сетевых вопросов. Пытался написать аналогичную программу на Golang:

```
data := []byte(`{"username":"zidle"}`)
r := bytes.NewReader(data)
resp, err := http.Post("http://formm.ru/handler.php", "application/json", r)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
} 

fmt.Println(resp.Status, resp.Header)
```

Выдает `200 OK и Headers`:

```
200 OK map[Content-Type:[text/html; charset=windows-1251] Date:[Sun, 26 Nov 2017 21:36:39 GMT] Server:[Apache/2.2.22 (Wi
n32) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.3.13] X-Powered-By:[PHP/5.3.13] Content-Length:[6]]
```

Но не заносит данные в БД, то есть `POST-запрос` на форму не выполняется. 
Тот же код на Python 3x:

```
import requests

paramss = {
    "username" : "zidle"

}

req1 = requests.post("http://formm.ru/handler.php", data=paramss)
print(req1.status_code, req1.headers, req1.text)
```

Все отлично работает, запрос в БД успешно поступает. То есть `POST запрос` на форму отработал.

В чем проблема?

Comment: попробуйте data := []byte(`{"form": {"username": "zidle"}}`) похоже что питон это делает

Comment: похоже всё ещё проще `data := []byte("username=zidle"})`

Comment: @biosckon не работает :/ Все ровно приходит 200 запрос но не отправляются данные post запросом.

Comment: для истории ваш надо было изменить Content-Type на `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` как вы и зделали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена данным кодом:

```
request_url := "http://formm.ru/handler.php"
// 要 POST的 参数
form := url.Values {
    "username": {"helloBD"},
}

body := bytes.NewBufferString(form.Encode())
rsp, err := http.Post(request_url, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer rsp.Body.Close()
body_byte, err := ioutil.ReadAll(rsp.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(body_byte))
```